# How do I determine which platform a specific detox test is running on?

Tags: react-native, detox

When using detox matcher by class name  i.e. `by.type(className)`
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md#bytypeclassname

Is it possible to change the classname depending on the platform the test is running on (ios/android)

e.g. `element(by.type(className))` becomes:

- `element(by.type('android.widget.ImageView'))` on android
- `element(by.type('RCTImageView'))` on ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `device.getPlatform()` to determine the current device platform.

Documentation:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicegetplatform

Example:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/240a709c609addf8b67e2ed6b91cba1293ad76c8/detox/test/e2e/03.actions.test.js#L124